# Framework not found GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

I'm getting that "Framework not found GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport" error after `pod update`. I have tried many clean build folder and project. But It still stays in there. What should I do?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Go to your project's target `Build Settings` > Search `GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport`.

You will see `Other Linker Flags`.

Remove these lines below:

```
-framework
GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport
```

After clean and build again, It should work as expected.

Comment: The problem is that when we do a ```pod install``` this shows up again.

Comment: So I guess this happens because pods upgraded to a newer version of firebase that doesnt use GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport but the linker flags do not reflect this?