# Framework not found in Xcode 11.6

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

After a pod update (pod deintegrate -> pod install) I get the following error:

> ld: framework not found GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I tried this answer to no effect.
[Framework not found GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63036273/framework-not-found-googledatatransportcctsupport)

In my Pods folder in Xcode I have no such framework, however I do have GoogleDataTransport.framework (from [ld: framework not found Pods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865899/ld-framework-not-found-pods)).

**Why does Xcode look for GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport.framework and how can I solve this?**

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that this answer ([Framework not found GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63036273/framework-not-found-googledatatransportcctsupport)) worked after all. I don't know what I did wrong the first 100 tries.